# Get all possible neighbour coordinates

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, combinations

I represented a 3D coordinate with a tuple of type `(Int, Int, Int)`

To get the *direct neighbours of a coordinate* I did something like this :

```hs
neighbours (x,y,z) =
    [(x',y',z') | x' <- [(x-1)..(x+1)], y' <- [(y-1)..(y+1)], z' <- [(z-1)..(z+1)], (x,y,z) /= (x',y',z')]
```

Now, I need to use 4D coordinates too, I could do something very similar to get the neighbours with a tuple of 4 elements and it would work. But, I would need to duplicate all the functions I did for the 3D coordinates, this time for 4D coordinates.

To avoid this, I thought of basically replacing tuples with a list of `Int`, now for a 3D coordinate it would be for example `[9, 3, 0]` and a 4D coordinate `[5, 1, 0, 1]` and so on.

How can I get the neighbours with an array of `Int` ? I tried using list comprehension but I failed finding a solution.

PS: I am new to Haskell and functional programming

Comment: It's a lot less to duplicate if you implement it as `neighbors (x,y,z) = delete (x,y,z) $ range ((x-1, y-1, z-1), (x+1, y+1, z+1))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could proceed recursively, and implement (N+1)-D neighbours in terms of N-D neighbours.

Essentially, if you have a (N+1)-D point `[x1,...,xNplus1]` this is of the form `x1 : xs` where `xs` is an N-D point. So, if you already know the list of neighbours of `xs`, you can turn that into the list of neighbours of `x1 : xs`.

Here's a simple attempt, which should almost work.

```
almostNeighbours :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
almostNeighbours []     = [[]]
almostNeighbours (x:xs) =
   [ x' : xs'
   | x' <- [x-1 .. x+1] , xs' <- almostNeighbours xs ]
```

Note that we do include the point itself in the list of neighbours. Failing to do so would not produce enough points in the recursive case. (I recommend convincing yourself this is indeed the case.)

If you do not want the point itself, you can always remove it later using an additional function, without affecting the recursive definition.

Finally, note that the code above probably won't be as fast as your original one, since lists are slower to access than tuples.

---

Minor alternative: using applicative style we can shorten the code slightly.

```
almostNeighbours :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
almostNeighbours []     = pure []
almostNeighbours (x:xs) = (:) <$> [x-1 .. x+1] <*> almostNeighbours xs
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly what I was looking for, and it makes perfect sense now that I see it. Will definitely remember that. Can't thank you enough!